# Why the background color of the top bar changes automatically not as I set it? Material Design 3

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, material-components-android

I'm trying to change the background color of the top bar and make it like the main background. I'm using [Material You (MD3)](https://m3.material.io/).

The user can change from light mode to dark mode or vice versa.

**Here is what I tried to do:**

*values\themes.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/md_theme_light_background</item>
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

*values-night\themes.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App" parent="Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/md_theme_dark_background</item>
        ...
    </style>
</resources>
```

*colors.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="md_theme_light_background">#FCFDF7</color>
    <color name="md_theme_dark_background">#1A1C19</color>
    ...
</resources>
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:title="@string/app_name" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

*The result (Dark mode)*

[image]

As you can see the background color of the top bar must be `#1A1C19` but it became `#222E22`, From where did the `#222E22` come?

I tried to find anything talking about this inside MD3 documentation, But did not find anything. Could you tell me why the color is changing automatically?

> Note: If I changed `md_theme_dark_background` from `#1A1C19` to `#1A1C18`, The background color of the top bar will be the same as the main background and will not change. But when return it to `#1A1C19` it will convert it to `#222E22`.

Is this normal behavior or it is a bug?

Thank you.

Comment: did u tried removing elevation ?

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo Yes I tried and that is working, But I want to keep the elevation attribute, Any other solution?

Comment: u can disable elevation overlay color by adding this line to the theme : `<item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>`

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo It's working in the general theme, But when creating a theme inherited from `@style/Widget.Material3.Toolbar.Surface` and I gave it `<item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>`, The attribute will not affect the app bar, Inside the app bar, I changed this also `style="@style/testTheme"`

Comment: `elevationOverlayEnabled`  is a theme attribute

Comment: inherit from this `ThemeOverlay.Material3.Toolbar.Surface`

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo Watch [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntd47.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgw17.png), [Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEQBD.jpg), There is a space on right and left.

Comment: @DrHowdyDoo If I give it a background color that will return me to the first problem. I'm very confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The different color is due to [elevation overlay](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/dark-theme#:%7E:text=Elevation%20overlays,on%20the%20canvas.).
You can either remove the elevation or disable the elevation overlay.

To disable elevation overlay in the theme add this line in your theme :

```
<item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>
```

To disable it only for the materialToolBar :

```
<style name="Card" parent="Widget.Material3.Toolbar.Surface">
     <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.Card</item>
 </style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.Card" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.Toolbar.Surface">
    <item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Then add this line in your materialToolBar xml code :

```
style="@style/Card"
```

Comment: [Look at app bar container attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBlpT.png), The default value of elevation is 4dp, Which means if I don't set elevation attribute then the default value will be 4dp, But if I do not set elevation attribute the default value will be 0dp, Why? This is a side question not required to answer. Your answer is working, Thank you.

Comment: the default value is 0dp when the app bar is not lifted, and 4dp if the app bar is lifted.